# How to get the details of bar code by capture the image in objective-c ..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image, barcode

I want to get all details of bar code by capture the image. please anyone can suggest how to implement them.

Comment: You want to make barcode scanner?

Comment: Yes, and i want to use in our app at anywhere.

Comment: If you want to scan QR codes that are used everywhere now than you can use xcode library AVFoundation for that. If you want to scan only barcode than you have to use third party library